# Google Cloud Platform: Updating a project after deployment

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, deployment, web-deployment, continuous-deployment

I am using Google Cloud to deploy my application. I have followed the steps in the documentation for deploying. I deployed early on in my project and it was successful. I then decided to change some files and update some features in my app. For this i followed the documentation for updating a deployment. This update was successful. It had me create the deployment in my Deployment Manager and run the gcloud commands to commence update. When I redeployed with gcloud app deploy, it was successful.

I have since added a couple more lines of code and features in my application. I followed the same documentation for updating a deployment as I had the first time I made an update and it is no longer working for me.

Does anybody have any idea what would be the problem? Again, I was able to successfully deploy, and even update that deployment once by following Google Cloud docs. Now I am having no luck.

Comment: " it is no longer working" means it doesn't deploy or, after deploying, the app is not accessible? or something else? what did you change in your application?

Answer (score 1):

Have you been changing the version number?  Go to:

https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions?project=< your project name >&serviceId=default

And make sure the version you want is active.  Also, you can try:

```
http://<VERSION>-dot-<SERVICE>-dot-<PROJECT_ID>.<REGION_ID>.r.appspot.com
```

Example:

```
https://20200813-dot-myapp.uc.r.appspot.com
```

if the version number was `20200813` and your appname is `myapp` and the region is `uc`